# How to assert response code in Rails controller test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

**EDIT**
Edited to change to a question about the test rather than code, as I see the application behaves correctly.

I'm writing a Rails 3 app which is purely a RESTful web service (i.e. no views). I have a User model, where the username is unqiue

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_uniqueness_of :username
end
```

In my controller, I have the following code to handle a new user being created:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request.raw_post))
  if @user.save
    puts "Added user #{@user.username}"
    format.json { render :json => "" }
  else
    puts "Failed to add user: #{@user.errors.to_json}"
    render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

I then have a functional test which creates a user with the same username as an existing user:

```
test "should not create user with duplicate username" do
  @jim = users(:jim)
  post '/users', @jim.to_json, "CONTENT_TYPE" => "application/json"
  assert_response :unprocessable_entity
end
```

When I run the test, the controller outputs "Failed to add user: {"username":["has already been taken"]}" as expected, but the test fails:
Expected response to be a <:unprocessable_entity>, but was <200>

However, with curl I get the response I expect:

```
curl -i -X POST -d '{"username": "james", "email": "test@test.com" }'
HTTP/1.1 422
{"username":["has already been taken"]}
```

So where am I going wrong with the assertion in the test?

Comment: Check if you wrap "render json:..." in format.json {render json:...} help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that I'd switched to using RackTest to allow me to post JSON in the body (i.e. not as a form parameter.) As a result, I should have been making assertions on last_response (the RackTest MockResponse used in the post call) instead of using assert_response:

```
  test "should not create user with duplicate username" do
    @jim = users(:jim)
    post '/users.json', @jim.to_json, "CONTENT_TYPE" => "application/json"
    assert_status :unprocessable_entity
  end

  def assert_status(expected_status)
    assert_equal last_response.status, Rack::Utils.status_code(expected_status)
  end
```

I am quite surprised assert_response :success passes when no methods have been called which yield a value for @response. If that assertion failed, or threw an exception, it would have been easier to track down my bug, but c'est la vie!

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use `respond_with`. It will take care of lots of REST logic, including setting status codes.

Also, Rails may be overkill for an application that's just a REST service. You might want to consider Sinatra instead.

Comment: respond_with doesn't seem to make a difference. Thanks for the suggestion on Sinatra. This is just a spike at the moment to see how suitable Rails is - I was also going to evaluate Sinatra...sounds like it could be the way to go

Comment: What do you mean when you say that `respond_with` doesn't make a difference? How have you been trying to use it?